# WPF Xceed DataGridControl - CellEditorBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, xceed

I'm working on the known problem about combobox binding in XCeed DataGridControl. Reading examples I saw the xwpf:CellEditorBinding property, but if I try to write `CellEditorBinding` in my XAML editor I get an error because `CellEditorBinding` is not defined. What's wrong?

```
<xmlns:wpfTool2="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Datagrid"
[...]
SelectedValue="{wpfTool2:CellEditorBinding}"/>
```

type `wpfTool2:CellEditorBinding` was not found

Comment: Add this namespace `xmlns:wxyz="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Markup;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid"` with whatever namespace prefix (wxyz) you like.